# PyCharm - пишется слэш при переносе строки

Tags: python, pycharm

Работаю в PyCharm.
При переносе строки в кавычках пишется еще одни кавычки и слэш:
Чего я такого подрубил - так и не понял)

[image: Начало:]

[image: После переноса:]

[image: Итог:]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 4):

Это [метод переноса строк кода обратным слэшем](https://tirinox.ru/new-line/#:%7E:text=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC.%20%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8D%D1%88%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%20%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%20(%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)%3A%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D1%83%D1%8E%20(%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB.%20explicit%20line%20joining)%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%8B%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%3A).
Применяется для форматирования кода, на саму строку в переменной `link` это не влияет. Если вам нужно сделать переносы строки внутри текста, можете воспользоваться `\n` или тройными кавычками:

```
txt0 = '123' \
       '45' \
       '65'

txt1 = '123\n' \
       '45\n' \
       '65'

txt2 = """123
45
65"""

print(txt0) # несмотря на переносы \, текст выведется в одну строку
print(txt1) # текст выведется в 3 строки
print(txt2) # текст выведется в 3 строки
```

```
1234565
123
45
65
123
45
65
```